# subclass unittest does not inherit attributes from parent class

Tags: python, unit-testing, inheritance

```
# parent
class Parent(unittest.TestCase):
   @classemthod
   def setUpClass(cls):
      cls.attr1 = '123'


# real test
class TestMe(Parent):

   @classmethod
   def setUpClass(cls):
      cls.attr2 = '456'
      super(Parent, cls).setUpClass()
```

But if we try to access `attr1` from `TestMe`, the interpreter will say the attribute does not exist.

I also tried to add `__init__` in `TestMe` but didn't help.

Any idea why I can't do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try passing `cls` into the class method: `super(Parent, cls).setUpClass(cls)`

Comment: @Blender Thanks, but `TypeError: setUpClass() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`

Comment: It looks like you can't have `setUpClass` in the child. If you name `setUpCalss2` in your child, it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `super` as you intended.  You are asking for the superclass of Parent, so you end up calling `unittest.setUpClass`, which of course does nothing.

Change it to

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    super(TestMe, cls).setUpClass()
```